# Image quality decrease when retrieving from SQL Server using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using ASP.NET to build a webpage which allow user to upload images. I use the following code to convert image to image byte:

```
FileUpload img = (FileUpload)fileUploadLocationPic;
Byte[] imgByte = null;
string strFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(img.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());

// Create a FILE
HttpPostedFile File = fileUploadLocationPic.PostedFile;

// Create byte array
imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];

// force control to load data
File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
```

Then I save `imgByte` into SQL Server. But when I retrieve image byte from SQL Server, I can see that the image quality has decreased. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The way I show image is using `ashx` handler:

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "SELECT [ChargingBoxLocationImage] FROM [Parking Lot] WHERE [ID] = @PLID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLID", PLID);
        connection.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
        }
```

And then in `aspx`, use

```
imageChargingLocation.ImageUrl = "~/Editor/ShowImage.ashx?PLID=" + strPLID;
```

[image: original]
[image: retrieved]

It will be obvious to see the difference if you zoom in.

Comment: If it's the very same sequence of bytes there is no way that quality decreases. I suggest you hunt where your transforming the image without realizing it. Could be anywhere, impossible to know from the information you've given.

Comment: @zespri I updated how I retrieve the image, please take a look at, thank you!

Comment: They are of different file size. Dimensions are also different. (one is three pixels wider) What size (for this image) do you have in the database?

Comment: @zespri thats the screen shot of the picture, just want you guys to see the different. But yes, I shouldn't use screen shot. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: @zespri When I tried to save retrieved image, it actually is not image type but ShowImage.ashx type. Is that the reason?

Comment: Show all of `ShowImage.ashx` your problem is likely in the rest of your ashx handler, the problem is not in the snippet you posted.

Comment: Taking screenshots and editing them with a program to fit is not going to help to diagnose the issue. You better post the exact file that you are uploading, and then the exact file you browser serves from the DB. Not a guarantee but still better than the screenshots

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted is fine since you are copying the bytes directly from the image.  What does your code look like that reads the data and sends it to the client?

As long as you don't load the bytes into a `Bitmap` and then call `Bitmap.Save`, your code will not decrease the image quality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my post with my way to show image which has quality decreased.

Comment: What image file types have you tried?  I don't see any problems.

Comment: I tried jpg type because I want image size less than 1mb.